# I'm facing some issues with pip version 20.1.1. Down below is the exact error I'm getting from pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Here is the stacktrace I get from `pip`. I'm running Windows 10.
What to do here?
I can see the pip version and other options with main but can't download / install any packages.

```
D:\Python>python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
        sys.exit(_main())
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
        command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
        module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
      File "D:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
        from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
        from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 7, in <module>
        from . import _inputstream
      File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip._vendor import webencodings
    ImportError: cannot import name 'webencodings' from 'pip._vendor' (D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Is it really vital that you upgrade `pip` before installing other packages? Generally slightly old versions of `pip` work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to broken build process just revert the pip version.
Try this:
$ pip install -U "pip<20" setuptools